# Invalid Syntax in print

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, slice

```
print("inventory[", start,":", finish, "] is", end=" ")
```

This line of code has my program stuck. It didn't like the spacing so I eliminated it and  now it is flagging the colon as invalid syntax. It is straight from my textbook and is a lesson about slicing lists. What am I missing?

Comment: I see no reason why this shouldn't work, post a copy of the error and perhaps we can work it out. The most likely options are that `start` and/or `finish` are not defined, or if there is a missing parentheses or bracket on the previous line (as @m00am suggests)

Answer (score 1):

For me this code works perfectly if `start` and `finish` have been defined.

This error can originate from a SyntaxError in the line before the print. Most certainly you are missing a parens or a bracket.

As an example consider the following code:

```
print(42 # closing parens intentinally missing here
print(23)
```

When executed this raises the following error:

```
File "foo.py", line 2
    print(23)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

As you can see the SyntaxError shows one line after the actual error. I suggest you check the line before your print statement.